# Is it possible to integrate Jenkins and whatsapp?

Tags: jenkins, hudson, jenkins-plugins, whatsapp, hudson-plugins

Is it possible to integrate Jenkins and WhatsApp?

Trying to send notifications from Jenkins on build status

Comment: Is there a Whatsapp API in Java/groovy/rest?